# Using Google Analytics on a SaaS webapp with custom domains

Tags: google-analytics, saas

Async Google Analytics works with multiple trackers [just fine](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands). However, I wonder if it will work as good in the following scenario.

We're developing a SaaS webapp where users can use custom domains (usual CNAME trick). More specifically, imagine `http://customer-foo.example.com` being a subdomain where `customer-foo` can access his data. Now this customer points a CNAME record of `example.customer-foo.com` to `example.com`. And here's a problem I see coming: we have a separate Google Analytics account to track usage across all "tenants", but it's set up to work on multiple subdomains of `example.com`.

How do I set up Google Analytics to correctly track visits on absolutely any domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha. Seems like [Cross-Domain Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html) covers this topic, and [this](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55503) article covers it some more.

Comment: The analytics.js version is here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain